# How can I insert new data into my queries in SQL without having the insert option?

Tags: mysql, sql

Due to my access rights I can not use insert to put data into existing tables. I am using case function to create new columns which I then use to obtain some upload data. However, I need to put additional values to end result but I dont know how can I do that

Example:

```
Select
substr(ACCOUNT_NO,4,1) Account_Type
,case ... end as F_Code
,case ... end as F_Position
,SGBL.balance_by_eoy ... balance_eur 

,case ... end||';;'||case...end||';'||replace(Round(...),'.',',')|| "13X09;10;X1;2018"
```

from SGBL

My end result looks like

```
Account_type  F_code  F_Position  balance_eur  13X09;10;X1;2018
-Income       15000   32400       180,12       15000;;32400;180,12
-Expense      14000   33500       320,87       14000;;33500;320,87
```

I would like to add new row such as

```
-income  15000 32400  -12,11 15000;;32400;-12,11
```

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Well, it strange that you have to do such a thing but if you want just to add an extra row to result of the query with static data you can use UNION ALL. By the way, your query doesn't return the same number of columns you presented in the sample result.

```
Select
substr(ACCOUNT_NO,4,1) Account_Type
,case ... end as F_Code
,case ... end as F_Position
,case ... end||';;'||case...end||';'||replace(Round(...),'.',',')|| "13X09;10;X1;2018" 
from SGBL
UNION ALL
SELECT '-income' Account_Type ,15000 F_Code,32400 F_Position,'-12,11' "13X09;10;X1;2018" FROM DUAL;
```

Comment: Thank you Jacek, I am new so I forgot to add one of the column. I will try your suggestion. Thanx a lot again